# nodejs - array search and append

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I need a help from node experts... Version I must use is 0.10.x

I have an array like this:

```
[ 
    [ 'ABC', '5' ] ,
    [ 'BCD', '1' ]
]
```

and I have new values to enter `[ 'DDD', '3' ]` and `[ 'ABC', '4' ]` and what I would like to achieve is to search if first column exists in array - if yes sum up second column, if not just add values to the array.

In result I would expect to have:

1. add `[ 'DDD', '3' ]` - DDD does not exist in array to it will be added

   `[ 
       [ 'ABC', '5' ] ,
       [ 'BCD', '1' ] ,
       [ 'DDD', '3' ]
   ]`
2. add `[ 'ABC', '4' ]` - ABC exist in array so second column will be summed up for ABC

   `[ 
       [ 'ABC', '9' ] ,
       [ 'BCD', '1' ] ,
       [ 'DDD', '3' ]
   ]`

Please help

Comment: Your source array doesn't relate to what you want to achieve? Have you got a better example?

Comment: @Ryad - i am not so skilled so i did not try anything...

Comment: @Alex - maybe I not explained steps so I will update it once again

Comment: I think you need to work with objects(also known as associative arrays) instead of arrays for what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objects initial value:

```
var myObj = [{'ABC': '5'}, {'BCD': '1'}]
```

Now if `DDD` doesn't exists, just add it:

```
var DDD = "3"
var DDDExists = false;

myObj.forEach(function(){
  if(this.DDD.length > 0){
    // If it exists, break the loop
    DDDExists = true;
    break;
  }
})

// If DDD doesn't exists, add it
if(DDDExists === false){
  // Add DDD object to array
  myObj.push({'DDD': 3});
}
```

Now if `ABC` exists, sum `ABC` to all the available values:

```
// Check if ABC exists
var ABCExsits = false;

myObj.forEach(function(){
  if(this.ABC.length > 0){
    // If ABC exits, break the loop
    ABCExists = true;
   break;
  }
})

if(ABCExists === true){

  // Sum all the values
  var totalSum = 0;

  myObj.forEach(function(){
    // Since we don't know the name property of the obj, we need to do a for loop
    for(var prop in this){
      totalSum = totalSum + this[prop];
    }    
  })

  // Now add `totalSum` to ABC

  myObj.foreach(function(){
    if(this.ABC.length > 0){
      this.ABC = totalSum;
      break;
    }
  })

}
```